# Show that graph of a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function is a $\mathcal{C}^k$-equivalence.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

$\textbf{The question is as follows:}$

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a map of class $\mathcal{C}^k$, $k=0, \ldots, \omega.$ Show that $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^d \to {\rm Graph}(f)$, $x \mapsto (x,f(x)),$ is a $\mathcal{C}^k$-equivalence.

Can someone please let me know what does $\mathcal{C}^k$-equivalence means here?

I think it can be an equivalence relation iff $f$ is the identity map, because we need to have $ x \to (x,x)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this context I can only think that "equivalence" means "diffeomorphism", as in $\varphi$ being a $C^k$-diffeomorphism.

Since ${\rm id}_{\Bbb R^d}$ is $C^\infty$ (hence $C^k$) and $f$ is $C^k$, then $\varphi = {\rm id}_{\Bbb R^d}\times f$ is $C^k$. The inverse is the restriction of the projection $(x,y)\mapsto x$ to ${\rm Graph}(f)$, which is $C^\infty$ (hence $C^k$).

Comment: Many thanks for your nice answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)